# AWS event for S3 bucket creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How do I run a lambda upon new bucket creation? I looked at supported S3 event types but couldn't find one for `BucketCreated` or equivalent.

Can CloudWatch help in this case?

Comment: Note that you may be going in a bad design direction if you have a need for an event on bucket creation.  [*"Amazon S3 is focused on get, put, list, and delete operations. Because bucket operations work against a centralized, global resource space, it is not appropriate to create or delete buckets on the high-availability code path of your application. It is better to create or delete buckets in a separate initialization or setup routine that you run less often."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the consumption of the event is not in a critical functional path; it is for security monitoring and enforcement purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine **CloudTrail** with **CloudWatch** to create an *Event* when a new S3 bucket is created. This example describes exactly that: **[CloudWatch Event Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html#events-for-services-not-listed)** (down the bottom under *Events for Services Not Listed*).

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks. I'll give this a spin shortly and confirm.